# Finding the $H$-orbit of $W$ using either Magma or Gap.

Tags: group-theory, gap, magma-cas

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $W$ is a subset of $G$. How I could find the $H$-orbit of $W$ by using either Magma or Gap (where $G$ acts upon $W$ by conjugation).

Comment: If $W$ is a set (i.e. sorted), simply calling Orbit(H,W,OnSets); computes the orbit in GAP.

Comment: Doesn't the 6 up votes indicate that this is, perhaps, not so off-topic as you thought?

Comment: @JamesMitchell: yes, I'd suggest to the author of the question to edit the question - then [it will be added to the reopening queue for the review](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Perhaps indicating what are $G$, $H$, $W$ in some particular application would be useful.